# Using subPath on method with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs

I'm trying to create an API using JAX-RS with multiple ways to get products. So if you type for example

herp.com/products/11

You get the product with ID 11, this works perfectly. And if you type:

herp.com/products/name/banana

You should get all products called banana. Although the get by name functionality doesn't work (the in-parameter name is always null). Here's the function with all annotations.

```
@GET
@Path("/name/{name}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getByName(@PathParam("{name}") String name) {

    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.INFO, "getByName, name: " + name);
    List<ProductProxy> found = new ArrayList<ProductProxy>();
    for(ProductProxy proxy : products)
        if(name.equals(proxy.getName()))
            found.add(proxy);

    return Response.ok(found).build();
}
```

Although the in-paremeter always is null. Am i doing something wrong with the annotations?? The class anotation is @Path("products").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curly braces from your path param, i.e. change

`@PathParam("{name}") String name`

to

`@PathParam("name") String name`

The braces in the `@Path("foo/{bar})` just identify that you have a path parameter named `bar`, but aren't a part of the parameter's name.